# Command /Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 10

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

I am getting the error even if I create a new project ... This is the new 4.2 SDK : iOS 5 beta 3

```
CompileStoryboard testing/en.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboard
    cd /Users/omkarjadhav/Desktop/testing
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH /Developer/usr/bin/..
    /Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/omkarjadhav/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testing-ejcbqbpaoxybvzazttgunhdfmtww/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/testing.app/en.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboardc /Users/omkarjadhav/Desktop/testing/testing/en.lproj/MainStoryboard.storyboard --sdk /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk

Command /Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 10
```

Its driving me crazy please help

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Did a

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

and reinstalled the SDK .. Working fine now .

Answer (score 21):

you just need to click "Run" in xcode. it will work again!

Comment: This is all I had to do as well when trying to build for archiving.  Just ran it again and it worked fine.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. As you said, I clicked on "Run" in Xcode but it is not working for me. I am using Xcode 6.1.1 version.

Comment: try several things : build clean , delete the derived data

Answer (score 0):

For me this went away after restarting my computer. It is probably an issue with a process locking whatever XCode is trying to link, but if all else fails, you can try restarting.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.

Copying my code to a brand new project solved the issue :S