# XCode 4.6.3 showing link error ibtool failed with exit code 10

Tags: xcode, xcode4.6.3

I installed XCode 4.6.3. Initially I was able to successfully able to build and run my code on it. However, all of a sudden when trying to configure my build on my iOS device, the build failed and showed the following error message - Command/Applications/Xcode 4.6.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 10

I tried various methods. I cleaned the App. I reinstalled Xcode. I deleted keys and certificates from Keychain Access. Its of no use. The Xcode is always showing this same error message. I created a fresh new sample project in this Xcode, it is still showing the same error message.

My Mac machine previously was Snow Leopard. I recently upgraded it to Lion OS X version 10.7.5

Please tell me what I should do to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752961/command-developer-usr-bin-ibtool-failed-with-exit-code-10)?

Answer (score 0):

Try making a clean new project, and see if the error persists.
And make sure you don't delete any important files like the
main storyboard or any xib-files.